# FileReferenceList: Forcing browse() dialog box to stay on top

Tags: actionscript-3, filereferencelist

This is probably going to be a simple question, but I can't seem to find my answer online after searching.

I am using the following simple code:

```
var fileReferenceList:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
fileReferenceList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelect);
fileReferenceList.browse();
```

A big flash button triggers this code, which works perfectly fine. Unfortunately, I don't enforce that the button cannot be clicked while the dialog box to browse file is opened, so I get "Error: Error #2041: Only one file browsing session may be performed at a time." if I click on the button while the pop up dialog box is up.

A solution that I really like is the one that Google Docs has. It does not let you click on their button, above "Select files to upload" while the pop up dialog box is showed. Actually, this dialog box has a sort of priority: You can't click ANYWHERE on the page before you select files or cancel on this dialog box.

I would like to have the same behavior, not let the users click anywhere in my web page until this dialog box is done, just like Google Docs does it, but I can't seem to find how.

Any clue from anyone please?

Thank you very much,

Rudy

Comment: how about button.enabled = false (after calling .browse()) , then set enabled= true ( onSelect()) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the HTML file that embeds the SWF. In Windows/Firefox, the behavior of the "select file" dialog will differ depending on what Window Mode (wmode) you use in the EMBED tag in the HTML page.

If you use wmode="opaque" or wmode="transparent", then the "select file" dialog will not be modal, and you'll be able to click on the browser window itself to bring it to the foreground. (Also, you'll be able to minimize and even the browser window). This only seems to apply to Windows/Firefox; other browsers all appear to keep the "select file" dialog on top.

If you omit the wmode attribute (it defaults to "window"), or set it to "direct" or "gpu", then the "select file" dialog will be modal.

Modal "select file" dialog:

```
<embed src="Upload.swf" 
       wmode="window"
       quality="best" 
       scale="noscale" 
       swliveconnect="true" 
       salign="lt" 
       width="220" height="75" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
```

Non-modal "select file" dialog:

```
<embed src="Upload.swf" 
       wmode="opaque"
       quality="best" 
       scale="noscale" 
       swliveconnect="true" 
       salign="lt" 
       width="220" height="75" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Docs browse dialog is "modal" (meaning the focus can't go to anything else while the dialog is up). As far as I can tell, the FileReference dialog box should be modal by default. What browser are you testing this in?

As a workaround, you could put a transparent (or semi-transparent, for a dimming effect) overlay over the entire stage while the dialog is up. This won't prevent the focus changing, but it will prevent other buttons on the stage from being clicked. For example a class like this:

```
public class Overlay extends Sprite
{
    private static const BACKGROUND_OPACITY:Number = 0.40;

    public function Overlay(_stage:Stage)
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0x000000, BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _stage.stageWidth, _stage.stageHeight);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

That would be used like this (from the document class):

```
private var overlay:Overlay;

public function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    overlay = new Overlay(stage);
    stage.addChild(overlay);

    // ...

    fileReference.browse();

    // ...
}


public function onSelect(e:Event):void
{
    stage.removeChild(overlay);     // Also do this on cancel, and on errors
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I am testing in FireFox 3.6. I am testing my program in the same browser as I am using Google Docs, so it is strange that the dialog is modal for Google Docs and not for me. Is there a way to enforce it to be "modal" when I call the browse method please? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, about the transparent overlay, do you mean to make the flash wmode as transparent please? My flash wmode is actually already transparent.

Comment: @Rudy: For me (in all browsers I've tested in, though I didn't try FF 3.6, only 3.5) the FileReference browse dialog is modal without any special code. Perhaps it is because you are using a FileReference*List*. Also try specifying a `FileFilter` as an argument to browse (you never know). I've updated my answer about what I meant with the overlay idea (nothing to do with wMode).

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tried to just FileReference rather than FileReferenceList and add it a FileFilter, and it is not working. I will try your code now, thank you.

Comment: I am sorry Cameron, but I copy and pasted your code and it did not help with my problem. I can still click on the page, minimize it and everything else. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't know why the dialog box is not modal for you, sorry. The workaround code I posted should work, though I have not tested it. Are you passing it a reference to the document class's stage? It will not prevent minimizing or interfere with the webpage in any way, it will only cover the stage with a semi-transparent sprite. This should produce a "dimming" effect over the entire stage.

Comment: I think the modal and non-modal difference lies in the platform. IIRC, flash on Mac shoots up a non-modal file browse dialog.